Is there a Chinese word for "self"?
The word/concept of "self" is present in the European tradition, notably with John Locke and his monograph An Essay Concerning Human Understanding (1689), and the Chapter XXVII on "Identity and Diversity".
Apparently, the words "self" and "personal identity" are rather synonymous in Locke (Nimbalkar 2011).
So I looked at the Chinese translation of the Essay 人類理解論 by 關琪桐, the Chapter XXVII, and these two words.
The translation for "personal identity" is 人格 (appears at Section 9).
The translation for "self" is 自我 (appears at Section 17).
As can be noticed, those words are composed of two characters, showing that they were probably constructed recently (19th or 20th century), maybe borrowing from Japanese translations (further investigation necessary here).
So my question is: was there a word/character for "self" in the Chinese language, prior to the 19th century, that is, in Chinese traditional elite culture?
I limit my question to the elite culture (the scholar-officials who were also often artists, like poets, painters and calligraphers).
In my impression, the word/character which comes close to it is 私, but its connotation is very different (it is negative).
This question is related to this one, although here I am talking about the "self".
References:
Nimbalkar, N. (2011). John Locke on personal identity. Mens sana monographs, 9(1), 268.
https://taiwanebook.ncl.edu.tw/en/book/NTUL-0529545/reader
http://www.philotextes.info/spip/IMG/pdf/essay_concerning_human_understanding.pdf


was there a word/character for "self" in the Chinese language, prior to the 19th century, that is, in Chinese traditional elite culture?

Yes, 吾 (同我) often can be interpreted as "self" in many writings, but specifically, "己" is the single Chinese character you are looking for.
己 (self; oneself) - "己所不欲，勿施于人 《論語·顏淵》"; “己欲立而立人，己欲达而达人 《論語·雍也》”; "推己所欲，以及天下 《傅子．卷一．仁論》- 後衍生 the idiom "推己及人".

(1) Thank you. Nonetheless, "self" in my question is a lexical word (a noun), referring to a philosophical concept (i.e. "personal identity"). A Chinese lexical word (an adjective) expressing a comparable concept is 私, but it means "private", and is very negatively connotated (alone, selfish, clandestine, illegal). https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A7%81/2257986

(2) However, 吾 (https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%BE/6093722) and 己 (https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B7%B1/5094945) are both pronouns, they basically mean "I". This is shown in the example sentences provided in your answer. From what I recall (please correct me if I'm wrong), 己 evokingly must  often be omitted in Classical Chinese...

I think you are taking it too far. because of cultural and philosophical differences, an English word might not have an exact match in Chinese, it is also true the other way around. None of the "己" can be omitted in the examples shown in my answer.

"None of the "己" can be omitted in the examples shown in my answer." this is because those examples are fixed expressions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phraseme#Non-compositional_phrasemes:_Idioms. (I upvoted your answer)

I don't think this conservation is constructive. I am done.

Quote:- "The word/concept of "self" is present in the European tradition." It should exist in non-European traditions as well as the concept of "Self" is a universal inherent trait of being human. The "problem" here is how is this "Self" expressed linguistically in the Chinese language in a way which is in congruent with the European tradition. A very very big topic which @r13 attempted to touch on. Here is Confucius's Concept of "Self"  https://www.tparents.org/UNews/unws9908/Klemme_confucian.htm


I am talking about the "self".

Which self would that be? Do people have more than 1 self? How can we tell them apart?
真我, 真实自我
true self, real self
自己:
做自己的主人，自己做决定吧。
Be your own man, make up your own mind.
自我:
她故作轻松地做了自我介绍。
Feigning casualness she introduced herself.
本人:
总统本人正在访问北京。
The President himself is just visiting Beijing.
